# Sidekiq + Rails: How to see queue of "Busy" jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a script that looks for jobs:

```
Sidekiq::Queue.new(queue_name).any? { |q| q.args[0] == blah_id } ||
Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.any? { |r| r.queue == queue_name && r.args[0] == blah_id } ||
Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.any? { |s| s.queue == queue_name && s.args[0] == blah_id }
```

However, this doesn't look inside of `Busy`:
[image]

How would I look inside of Busy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the `Sidekiq::Workers` API:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/90190e0dc40744cb07a12291e5ecc20b069981b6/lib/sidekiq/api.rb#L931

Comment: Link is now to `ProcessSet#clean_up`... is it meant to be `Workers#each` https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/90190e0dc40744cb07a12291e5ecc20b069981b6/lib/sidekiq/api.rb#L934 ?

Comment: fixed the link.